# Apache-Drill query parquet file: Error in parquet record reader

Tags: parquet, apache-drill, pyarrow

I've created a parquet file using Pyarrow and it can be queried using Pyspark. However it cannot be queried using Apache-drill(1.14), which was installed recently and can work with other data formats including csv, json and RDBs. Can someone help me troubleshooting what's going wrong and how can i fix it?  Thanks!

(I was able to run the count(*) query but cannot run query below)

Here is my query and the error message:

```
select * from dfs.`C:/Apache_Spark/sample_Sends_2017.parquet` limit 20;
```

Query execution failed

Reason:

```
SQL Error: INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: Error in parquet record reader.
Message: Failure in setting up reader
Parquet Metadata: ParquetMetaData{FileMetaData{schema: message schema {
optional int64 SendsID;
optional int64 SendJobsID;
optional int64 SendID;
optional binary EncryptIndivID (UTF8);
optional int64 SendDate (TIMESTAMP_MICROS);
optional int64 __index_level_0__;
}

, metadata: {pandas={"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "SendsID", "field_name": "SendsID", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}, {"name": "SendJobsID", "field_name": "SendJobsID", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}, {"name": "SendID", "field_name": "SendID", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}, {"name": "EncryptIndivID", "field_name": "EncryptIndivID", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "SendDate", "field_name": "SendDate", "pandas_type": "datetime", "numpy_type": "datetime64[ns]", "metadata": null}, {"name": null, "field_name": "__index_level_0__", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "int64", "metadata": null}], "pandas_version": "0.23.0"}}}, blocks: [BlockMetaData{1000, 46321 [ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [SendsID] optional int64 SendsID  [PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE, PLAIN], 4917}, ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [SendJobsID] optional int64 SendJobsID  [PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE, PLAIN], 6342}, ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [SendID] optional int64 SendID  [PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE, PLAIN], 6568}, ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [EncryptIndivID] optional binary EncryptIndivID (UTF8)  [PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE, PLAIN], 39530}, ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [SendDate] optional int64 SendDate (TIMESTAMP_MICROS)  [PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE, PLAIN], 41195}, ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [__index_level_0__] optional int64 __index_level_0__  [PLAIN_DICTIONARY, RLE, PLAIN], 45450}]}]}
Fragment 0:0
```

Comment: Did you kill drillbits ?

Comment: no, it's up. I can work with other data.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3059

Comment: Thanks, but i don't find any answer in the link...

Comment: It is not an answer. I feel Drill + parquet don't go well. Are you sure parquet file is valid?

Comment: yes, it can be queried using pyspark, no problem with that. I have other parquet sample files which can be queried by Drill though.

Comment: Does it throw any exception after `Fragment 0:0`?

Comment: no, it shows an Error Id: 0c8111d6-0587-4760-8b4f-cce2c447380b

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please create Jira ticket and provide file sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue [DRILL-6670](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6670) and resolved in current Apache Drill [master](https://github.com/apache/drill) branch. You can build Drill from this branch or wait for upcoming Drill 1.15.0 release version.

The issue is in the `optional int64 SendDate (TIMESTAMP_MICROS)` column.
You can try to exclude it from the query or convert it to BigInt, see more in [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6670).

Comment: Thanks! I tried this query and it worked: select cast(SendDate as date) as sendate, SendsID,  SendJobsID, SendID from dfs. `C:/Apache_Spark/sample_Sends_2017.parquet` limit 20;

Comment: Howerver, the column EncryptIndivID cannot be queried from parquet, which originally was a nvarchar(500) in csv file.

Comment: So at first try to identify the problem column. Does the following query work for you `select SendDate dfs. C:/Apache_Spark/sample_Sends_2017.parquet` ?
If the issue is in the `optional binary EncryptIndivID (UTF8)`, probably you have faced with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4464
In this case try to set store.parquet.use_new_reader to true and please let me know the result.